# Print a chart according to date

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, jfreechart

I get the result when I write the sql code without a where condition. I think the prepared statement did not access the date from `JDateChooser`.

```
private void datesearchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    try {
        JDBCCategoryDataset dataset = new JDBCCategoryDataset("jdbc:mysql://localhost:10061/goshope","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver","root","tiger");
        String qry= "select  item,SUM(quantity) from bill_electronics where date=?  GROUP BY item";
        ps= con.prepareStatement(qry);
        // String qry= "select item, SUM(quantity)  from bill_electronics GROUP BY (item)";

        SimpleDateFormat sdf=new  SimpleDateFormat(" dd,MM,YYYY");
        String date =datechart.getDateFormatString();
        ps.setDate(1,new java.sql.Date(datechart.getDate().getTime()));
        dataset.executeQuery(qry);
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("Daily Report","item", "qty", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,false, true, true);
        BarRenderer renderer = new BarRenderer();
        CategoryPlot plot=null;
        ChartFrame frame =new ChartFrame("Daily Report", chart);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        //  frame.setSize(400,650);
        ChartPanel chartpanel= new ChartPanel(chart);
        panel1.removeAll();
        panel1.add(chartpanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel1.validate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I think the prepared statement is not accessing the date from JDateChooser. If I Provide a particular date or without 'where' condition on sql code, then I get correct answer.

Comment: Plz help me..i think the prepare Statment is not accessing the date from JDateChooser.if i Provide a particular date or without 'where' condetion   on sql code , then i get correct answer.

Comment: DO NOT ADD parts to the question in the comments. Edit the question body instead. ALSO, please indent your code and maintain the standard formatting rules of Stack Overflow.

Comment: sure sir.i am a fresher in StackOverflow ,thatswhy  it happens... forgive me.....

Comment: datechart.getDate().getTime() gives you a date that is exactly (think seconds and millis too) what you have in your DB?

Comment: Don't _replace_ the chart; _update_ the dataset; see also these [Q&As](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20JDBCCategoryDataset).

Comment: #RC,   In my database i have date in year-month-date format without specifying time.                                                                            
                                                                                                
   java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
   //this is the code to insert date into my database table

Comment: Please send me a full code to solve this problem.

Comment: please help me.